# Low  frequency snake repellant

Tags: lowend

Hey guys I don't know if anyone here can help me, I have been contacted to create a sound that is going to chase snakes away, it isn't in the film industry, they want to be able to play it in a field to chase the snakes away, I have read that snakes pick up vibrations at a low frequency which would chase them away. I was just asking this question wondering if you guys has any ideas on how to create a sound like this?

Comment: How did your low frequency base and predator calls turn out? I have a similar requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this is the kind of project, where practicality through trail n error rules.

I think u need to have a snake first to start playing it different types of sounds at different intervals of time. Best way to test this out would be , when the snake is in its nocturnal sleep. As you know, most of the poisonous snakes are nocturnal. Meaning their senses like hearing & smelling is at its wake state. So when the snake generally sleeps in the daylight, would be the best time to start your experiment.

I suppose u would take at least 2 months to derive to an result. Making charts of the LF waves your passing through to see the reaction in a snake . Frankly speaking . im not even sure if they repel from LF sounds. From my understanding its a break through if you will be able to find a LF wave which will can repel snakes. Try to make patterns of LF. Various patterns having constant amplitudes. I mentioned constant amplitude because, Ultrasonic waves which many mammals, animals, reptiles repel from are of constant amplitute. Constantly giving constant amplitude of one frequency can be quite irritating for any living being, im sure u agree with that.

So good luck, try using sub-sonic woofers. And try out loads of test patterns on tat sleeping snake!

Stephen J
Acoustic Research Engineer

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps some voice clips of Samuel L. Jackson with aircraft engine noise in the background?

Sorry, couldn't [resist](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0417148/).

I'm not sure if they actually work, but there are lots of ultrasonic animal deterrent products (on the other end of the frequency spectrum). Google "ultrasonic snake repeller".

Comment: whahaha will definitely mix some of his dialogue over what ever i come up with


Comment: Haha, that totally put a smile on my face ;)

Comment: Ultrasonic pest repellers are [generally useless](http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/403/do-ultrasonic-bug-repellers-work), and in the case of snakes almost certainly useless since snakes don't have ears in the first place. They can only feel vibrations through the ground, and ultrasound can't propagate that way.

Answer (score 2):

Never heard of this personally, but it sounds like your talking about sounds way down in the frequency spectrum. Is your client aware of the size and number of sub-woofers they might have to lug around to pull this off (and the power needs of that kind of array)? Not to mention the need to test those sounds out in a controlled environment.

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard about something like this, so I can't help you directly. But if you have never done anything like this, I can't see how your client can expect you to figure it out on your own. Try calling your local university and ask to speak with a biologist. Or ask your your client where thy got the idea from - whoever told them about it hopefully know more about it. Also, wherever you read about the low frequencies it should have a source you can track down and read for yourself. If you have a starting point, it shouldn't be impossible to get a hold of somebody who knows about it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps looking at kookaburra recordings could provide some clues?

Comment: yes have come upon the idea that I should have a low frequency base and mix some calls of snake predators over it.

Answer (score 1):

From what I could find on the net, they are actually afraid of the vibrations, which they perceive as a larger creature attacking them.

People use vibrating machines to keep the snakes away. So maybe you can experiment with low frequency square waves, or percussive sounds (Like a kick drum or a click) played in quick succession.

This is the first time I am hearing about this method. Usually I can just tell snakes off because I am an Indian, we're all Slytherins. (Is it racism if I do it to myself?)